# How do I extend two types from a base type?

Tags: typescript

I have two types and a base type. The base type should really be an abstract type but I'm not sure the relevant terminology of what it should be called.

Base Type

```
type Base = { 
   color: string
   distance: number
}

type A = {
   size: string
}

type B = {
   rotation: number
}
```

I want both type A and B to extend the Base type. The base Type should never be used by itself and in the future a type C might exist. I know with classes I could declare an abstract Base class and then extend from it but I was looking to avoid that if possible.

I think this is possible using interfaces but I don't want someone to implement the Base type as it won't be a valid type and I would like to protect against that.

Comment: I don't understand. Why hamstring yourself by throwing away relevant tools in the OO toolbox to try and re-implement them in a different way? A wrench duct taped to a screw driver makes a poor hammer.

Comment: You can’t stop someone from implementing `Base` whether it’s an `interface` or a `type`, so you might as well use an `interface` if that’s what you want to do.  Otherwise you can use intersections, but the premise of the question seems to be untrue so it might be moot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Just don't export `Base` type.
2. I have added property with `never` type, so nobody is allowed to use `Base` pure type

```js
type Base = {
  color: string,
  distance: number,
  prevent: never,
}

export type A = Omit<Base, 'prevent'> & {
  size: string
}

export type B = Omit<Base, 'prevent'> & {
  rotation: number
}

// error, prevent property missing
// nobody can't create a variable with pure Base type
const x: Base = {
  color: 's',
  distance: 2
}

const y: A = {
  color: 's',
  distance: 2,
  size: 'm',
} //ok


const z: B = {
  color: 's',
  distance: 2,
  rotation: 90
} //ok
```

Does it work for you?

I just can't imagine other restictions

You can also add disallow `Base` name in your eslint configuration

I agree with @VLAZ and @jcalz - you can't have any guarantee

Comment: The `export` added in front of the definitions of `type A` and `type B` is not present in the question. Do not make a (bad) habit of exporting everything from a module. Export only the symbols that are really needed in the modules that use the current model. It is easy to export a private symbol later but it is very difficult and sometimes impossible to make private a symbol that has been exported.

Comment: @axiac I just assumed that using A an B is allowed, that's why I added `export` statement. I don't encourage nobody to export everything. This is just my solution of the problem

Comment: @VLAZ sorry for that typo

Comment: @captain-yossarian lol, it's not even the first time it has happened :)

Comment: @VLAZ, `Z` and `X` are just so close to each other )

Comment: Yeah, it's fine. Fun fact: I used to spell my name in lowercase `vlaz` but many people would mistake the lowercase L for an uppercase i, so I changed over to all caps.